# Remove ListViewItemPresenter border in Microsoft.UI.Xaml ListView

Tags: c#, windows, winui-3

I'm in the process of converting my UWP app to be a WinUI 3 app. I noticed there's a difference in the way `ListViewItem`s are displayed. The screenshots below show an added `Border` child to the `ListViewItemPresenter` in WinUI 3.

UWP

[image: UWP]

--

WinUI 3

[image: WinUI3]

The XAML for both is as simple as it gets:

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.Items>
        <ListViewItem>One</ListViewItem>
    </ListView.Items>
</ListView>
```

I'm wondering if there's a way to remove the extra `Border` element from the WinUI 3 `ListViewItemPresenter`. I noticed it has a default margin of 4, 2, 4, 2, which causes visual differences relative to my existing UWP app.

Comment: Here is the corresponding [GitHub issue](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/6358).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can remove the `Border` inside the `ListViewItemPresenter` but you can modify its `Margin` like this:

**MainPage.xaml**

```xml
<Grid>
    <ListView x:Name="CustomListView">
        <ListView.Items>
            <ListViewItem>One</ListViewItem>
            <ListViewItem>Two</ListViewItem>
            <ListViewItem>Three</ListViewItem>
        </ListView.Items>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```cs
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;
    }

    private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (ListViewItem listViewItem in this.CustomListView.FindChildrenOfType<ListViewItem>())
        {
            if (listViewItem
                    .FindChildrenOfType<ListViewItemPresenter>()
                    .FirstOrDefault() is ListViewItemPresenter listViewItemPresenter &&
                listViewItemPresenter
                    .FindChildrenOfType<Border>()
                    .FirstOrDefault() is Border border)
            {
                border.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Extensions.cs**

```cs
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> FindChildrenOfType<T>(this DependencyObject parent) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent); i++)
        {
            DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);

            if (child is T childOfT)
            {
                yield return childOfT;
            }

            foreach (T grandChild in child.FindChildrenOfType<T>())
            {
                yield return grandChild;
            }
        }

        if (parent is ContentControl contentControl)
        {
            if (contentControl.Content is T contentOfT)
            {
                yield return contentOfT;
            }

            if (contentControl.Content is DependencyObject dependencyObjectContent)
            {
                foreach (T grandChild in dependencyObjectContent.FindChildrenOfType<T>())
                {
                    yield return grandChild;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This works if you have pre-fixed items in the `ListView`. If you need to add items after the `Loaded` event, you need to apply this for the new items.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately we have dozens and dozens of listviews, each of which generally bind to an itemssource, so this approach would not be ideal. I'm hoping to find a way to override a style resource somehow.

Comment: We actually ended up doing something similar to this. We subclass `ListViewItemPresenter` and remove the margin of the found child border in `OnLoaded`. Still not a super clean solution, but better than anything else we've come up with.

Comment: @TylerSouthard Code sample woukd help. How do I get the ListView to use the sub class?

Comment: @Slion I posted an answer below (https://stackoverflow.com/a/76905148/5951996)

Answer (score 2):

I'm also struggling with the same issue, I've got one way which might be a little bit nicer depending on your preferences of course. Just get the styles of the listviewitempresenter from the themeresources file https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/blob/main/dev/CommonStyles/ListViewItem_themeresources.xaml then add a negative margin Margin="-4,-2.4,-4,-2.4" to neutralize the margin of the border. Still not a nice way and still looking for a better ways...

```
<ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                                    <ListViewItemPresenter Margin="-4,-2.4,-4,-2.4"  ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
                                    Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget="True"
                                    FocusVisualMargin="{TemplateBinding FocusVisualMargin}"
                                    FocusVisualPrimaryBrush="{TemplateBinding FocusVisualPrimaryBrush}"
                                    FocusVisualPrimaryThickness="{TemplateBinding FocusVisualPrimaryThickness}"
                                    FocusVisualSecondaryBrush="{TemplateBinding FocusVisualSecondaryBrush}"
                                    FocusVisualSecondaryThickness="{TemplateBinding FocusVisualSecondaryThickness}"
                                    SelectionCheckMarkVisualEnabled="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectionCheckMarkVisualEnabled}"
                                    CheckBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckBrush}"
                                    CheckBoxBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckBoxBrush}"
                                    DragBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragBackground}"
                                    DragForeground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragForeground}"
                                    FocusBorderBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemFocusBorderBrush}"
                                    FocusSecondaryBorderBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemFocusSecondaryBorderBrush}"
                                    PlaceholderBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackground}"
                                    PointerOverBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemBackgroundPointerOver}"
                                    PointerOverForeground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemForegroundPointerOver}"
                                    SelectedBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemBackgroundSelected}"
                                    SelectedForeground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemForegroundSelected}"
                                    SelectedPointerOverBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemBackgroundSelectedPointerOver}"
                                    PressedBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemBackgroundPressed}"
                                    SelectedPressedBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemBackgroundSelectedPressed}"
                                    DisabledOpacity="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDisabledThemeOpacity}"
                                    DragOpacity="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragThemeOpacity}"
                                    ReorderHintOffset="{ThemeResource ListViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}"
                                    HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                    VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                    ContentMargin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                    CheckMode="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckMode}" />
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: I would still get some overlap even with the exact negative margin. Setting the border margin to 0 as explained in other answers give you cleaner results.

Answer (score 1):

As requested, here is the solution my team ended up using:

```
public class BorderlessListViewItemPresenter : ListViewItemPresenter, IDisposable
{
    public BorderlessListViewItemPresenter()
    {
        Loaded += OnLoaded;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Loaded -= OnLoaded;
    }

    private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Border childBorder = this.FindChild<Border>();
        if ( childBorder != null )
            childBorder.Margin = new Thickness(0);
    }
}
```

Then you simply use this class in the XAML Style's `ControlTemplate` for overridden `ListViewItems` or `GridViewItems`, like the sample below:

[image: Sample using the overridden ListViewItemPresenter]

Comment: Thanks! I only needed to do that in one place so I could just use `Loaded="ListViewItemPresenter_Loaded"` instead of a subclass. Subclass is cleaner though if you have larger application. It avoids duplicating the patching code.